# Is it possible to use object/embed code to show an image+link?

Tags: html

I have a code like this that I cannot modify (its hosted elsewhere). I can control however the `player.swf` since its hosted on my domain.

```
<object width="480" height="388">
    <param name="movie" value="http://mysite.com/player.swf"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://mysite.com/player.swf" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="388" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always">
    </embed>
</object>
```

I'm interested in replacing the `player.swf` for a plain GIF or JPG image instead with a link elsewhere. I been trying to do it and I can link to an image but I can't add a link to it. Is there any way that this can be done without modifying the original object/embed code?

Answer (score 0):

I may have completely misread this question, but Ill chuck this in incase.

This would be the code for displaying an image, and when clicked, takes you to the .swf file.

```
<a href="http://www.LinkToObjectElsewhere.com" target="_blank"><img src="link/to/hosted/image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```